# SAXSource and org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I have a `javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource` and I would like to get a `org.w3c.dom.Document` object. I have already googled around for hours but I got frustrated.

Besides, the `InputSource` returned by `SAXSource#getInputSource()` is null and therefore I cannot use it to build the `org.w3c.dom.Document`.

By the way, what I'm trying to achieve is to remove some xml elements from the xml contained in the SAXSource.

Thank you for your help!

Just some pieces of info about my environment: the SAXSource is returned to me by the `invoke` method of the following javax.xml.ws dispatcher:

```
Service service = Service.create(serviceName);         
//...
javax.xml.ws.Dispatch<Source> dispatcher = 
        service.createDispatch(portName, Source.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would generally use this type with a [Transformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html):

```
//Source source = your SAXSource
DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
TransformerFactory.newInstance()
    .newTransformer()
    .transform(source, result);
Document doc = (Document) result.getNode();
```